# Spring boot synchronized access to static class

Tags: java, spring-boot, synchronization

I have to face a crappy library, in my Spring boot project (a RESTful Web Service), that use singletons and static classes, so when multiple clients use the RestController I have a synchronization problem:

I wrapped the usage of the library in a synchronized method but is useless, the concurrent usages continue to occur... I don't understand why and how can achieve the synchronized behavior.

Thanks for any help!

--- solution ---

As @Anthony suggested I used a ReentrantLock, you can see the implementation below.

The second problem derived from a violated assertion in the *generateModel* method that doesn't print error messages due to a problem with the logging library (another problem).

Problem solved, thanks.

--- code ---

```
public class ModelingLocker {
private static final ReentrantLock reentrantLock = new ReentrantLock();

private String modeling;
private File out;

public ModelingLocker(String modeling, File out) {
    this.modeling = modeling;
    this.out = out;
}

public File synchroModeling() throws EngineException {
    reentrantLock.lock();
    System.out.println(reentrantLock);
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(reentrantLock));
    try {
        long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        System.out.println(String.format("--start--> Thread=%d %s", id, modeling));
        ModelingEngine.generateModel(out);
        System.out.println(String.format("<--end-- Thread=%d %s", id, modeling));
    } finally {
        reentrantLock.unlock();
    }
    return out;
}
}
```

I use it within a

```
@Service
public class ModelingService {
//...
   @Async
   public Future<Void> model(File file, String message) {
      ModelingLocker modelingLocker = new ModelingLocker(message, file);
      if (isWellFormed(modelingLocker.synchroModeling()) {
         //...
      }
      return new AsyncResult<>(null);
   }

//...
}
```

This service is autowired within a rest controller and I need @Async because the *generateModel* method is a long task and I have to answer a 201 to the client

Comment: Where did you put the synchronized method? What object is being locked? If different threads lock on different instances of the class that contains the synchronized method, then they will not wait on each other.

Comment: Reentrant Lock should be the correct solution but does not work...

Comment: Then you most likely used it in the wrong way. Show what you've tried, so that people can comment on whether you are using it correctly or not.

Comment: @SimoneAonzo Glad that you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Reentrant Lock?
You may want to look at this link for example usage
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/03/reentrantlock-example-in-java-synchronized-difference-vs-lock.html

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work!
I wrapped the logic into a class with a static-initialized ReentrantLock but this object is different within different threads... so I don't understand why I have the problem with the static library!

Comment: sorry I was wrong: they are the same object but the lock method don't lock!

Answer (score 0):

Just synchronize the methods which should be accessed by one thread.